# Six circles in a larger circle!

Tags: geometry, circles

Six circles each of unit radius are being circumscribed by another larger circle. All the smaller circles touch each other. What is the circumference of the larger circle?
I tried many things, but being a beginner I am actually out of ideas now. Like, I tried joining the centre of all the circles to find the radius of the larger circle, but even that didn't work.

https://nzmaths.co.nz/sites/default/files/images/Six0.gif

The linked image shows the arrangement of the circles but all the circles are touching each other.

Comment: Are the six unit circles in any particular patters? Is one in the center and the other five around it? Are they all arranged in a hexagon (so that there is technically room for a seventh unit circle in-between them (that's a big hint, by the way)? Regardless, draw a figure, draw all radii to all tangent points, and the answer should appear.

Comment: I was not able to add a picture of the diagram as my reputation is not so high.

Comment: The circles are placed in a triangular pattern and form an equilateral triangle with 3 circles on one side.

Comment: You can tell by the way. and you can add a *link* to image

Comment: You can use words to describe it. You can upload the picture to some other site and link to it (you can link even though you can't embed images). What are these "many things" you have tried? Why do you think they didn't work?

Comment: https://nzmaths.co.nz/sites/default/files/images/Six0.gif

Comment: The linked image shows the pattern, but all the circles are touching each other.

Comment: Do not understand this: "all the smaller circles touch each other". Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you currently describe, we have the following relation between the bigger radius and smaller radius from simple trigonometry.

$$(R-r) \cos (30^\circ) = 2r$$

You can solve for $R$